# MySQL what kind of query i need to use

Tags: php, mysql

i'm making a panel where i can manage my users, i want to show username, email, and i want to show how much orders the placed. In my database i have 2 tabels 1 users, 1 orders. I'm saving the username from the user in the order table so i know wich user has bought it.

But, i want to write a panel with a overview from my users in a foreach loop. I have the loop for username, email how i can add the amount of order to it.

```
<?php
$model = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM user');
$adminAccounts = $model->queryAll();
foreach($adminAccounts as $results){
        $accounts['id'] = $account_id;
        $accounts['username'] = $results['username'];
        $accounts['email'] = $results['email'];
        $accounts['rest'] = $results;
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>"  . $newValidation->safeEcho($accounts['username']) ." </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>"  . $newValidation->safeEcho($accounts['email'])." </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Lets say my table look likes this

```
<username> <email>
```

Now i want it to look like this

```
 <username> <email> <total orders>
```

I was thinking i should use a inner join but how i can do that ?

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can change your query to:

```
SELECT user.*, t.cnt FROM user JOIN (SELECT gebruikersnaam, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM orders GROUP BY gebruikersnaam) t ON user.username = t.gebruikersnaam
```

With this query you can get users orders but you will skip users without orders, so to get them you can do LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT user.*, t.cnt FROM user LEFT JOIN (SELECT gebruikersnaam, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM orders GROUP BY gebruikersnaam) t ON user.username = t.gebruikersnaam
```

I suggested that the field for users in table orders is username. And in your question you point that the table is users but in your query table is user. I am using user. If you change your current query with this one you can add in your code:

```
foreach($adminAccounts as $results){
    $accounts['id'] = $account_id;
    $accounts['username'] = $results['username'];
    $accounts['email'] = $results['email'];
    $accounts['total_orders'] = ($results['cnt'] == NULL) ? 0 : $results['cnt']; // orders per user
    $accounts['rest'] = $results;
    echo "
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>"  . $newValidation->safeEcho($accounts['username']) ." </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>"  . $newValidation->safeEcho($accounts['email'])." </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>"  . $newValidation->safeEcho($accounts['total_orders'])." </p>
            </td>

        </tr>
    ";
}
```

Comment: I just see, that the cunt used instand username in his order table, he used gebruikersnaam its dutch for username, i'm not good at making join statements so what i need to change to gebruikersnaam ?. In user table, username, and in order table gebruikersnaam.

Comment: Yes, i see the query is fine, atleast no errors on that. Only i get a Undefined index: cnt

Comment: Yes, I edited again I typed $result['cnt'], should be $results['cnt'].